# Laravel 5 creating custom registration and login from default Authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-blade

After 2 years experience in cakePhp , recently i started learning laravel framework. i already created the database for my new project and create a default authentication system with laravel 5 using the

`php artisan make:auth` 
but i cant modify it according to my database design
i have a

- users table(id,username,password,remember_token)
- user_profiles table (id,first_name,last_name etc)
- group table(id,group_name)
- group_users(group_id,users_id)
- users_user_profiles (user_id,user_profile_id)

so using the above table i want to implement a group based user management system.

if i use the default authentication system ,

1. how can i store login and registration details into two tables with a single registration from? and how can i insert the id's into pivot table users_user_profiles table automatically ?
2. How to create a view for the registration which contain both the login details and registration details, how can i separate them and how to access the request data separately for storing into two separate tables?

if anybody can provide a detailed description on this, it will help all laravel 5 beginners, i think its a common problem for all newbies..
please help me 
Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the Eloquent ORM?

Comment: yes, i know about relationshiops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define good your models, so you can use eloquent, for example making connection with user_profiles:

```
    public function profiles()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('UserProfile');
    }
```

(It will be possible only when you get UserProfile model)
Then you extend your register form by adding first_name, last_name, etc. In auth controller after creating user

```
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
```

Add code that create user profile:

```
$userProfile = UserProfile::create([
        'first_name' => $data['name'],
        'last_name' => $data['email']
    ]);
```

Then add it to user by [attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) command (if you have many of them you can use [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships)) :

```
$user->userProfiles()->attach($userProfile->id);
```

More info about how user Authentication work you can find exterminating file: `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php`

Comment: What about updating pivot tables?
I have a group_user pivot table as mentioned  , how to update it after saving the user details automatically

Comment: Same as saving to users_user_profiles by $user->userProfiles()->attach($userProfile->id);

Comment: what i want is , when a user is registering using registration page, i am passing a hidden field as group_id . i want to automatically update my pivot table group_user when the user data saved.?

Comment: first find that group using `$group = Group::first($request('group_id');`
then add it to user `$user->groups()->attach($group);`
consider that passing group_id in hidden field can be big secure issue

Comment: is there any way to pass the group id? i have two registration form, one for user and one for employee and a common login page.how can we identify them on registration , other than passing hidden field

Comment: You can pass it like you do it but remember to make case statement for selected groups (white list) so user couldn't get access to for example admin groups