# Adding company registration to SaaS app Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am coming from codeigniter to laravel and still fairly new so excuse me if this is obvious.  I'm struggling with something that seems to be pretty simple but cannot find any info online but have found a few packages that come close.

I have added an input field on registration to capture the company name, once they click register it should add the user info to the user table like it does but also add company_name to the company_name column of the companies table.

*Company Table:*

```
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------+
| ID |  company_name  |   created_at   |  updated_at  |
+----+----------------+----------------+--------------+
```

*User Table:*

```
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| ID | company_id | name | email | password | remember_token | created_at | updated_at |
+----+------------+------+-------+----------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

*Companies Model:*

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Companies extends Model
{
    //
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_name',
    ];

}
```

*User Model:*

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function Company()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Companies');
    }
}
```

And in my AuthController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Companies;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'company_name' => 'required|min:5|unique:companies,company_name',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        $user->Company()->create(['company_name'=>$data['company_name']]);
        $user->attachRole(1); // parameter can be an Role object, array, or id
        return $user;
    }
}
```

*And finally here is the form in my register.blade.php*

```
<div class="register-box-body">
            <div class="register-box-body">
<p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
<form action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company name" name="company_name" value="{{ old('company_name') }}"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype password" name="password_confirmation"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="checkbox icheck">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Register</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div>
</form>
```

This all seems right based on [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817230/laravel-5-creating-custom-registration-and-login-from-default-authentication).  However when I register it just creates the user info in the `users` table with `company_id` being `0` and does not add anything to the `companies` table.

**How would I go about adding creating a field on registration for user to enter `company_name` and then when saved it adds to the `companies` table and stores the `company_id` in the `users` table?**

**-------------------------------------------
UPDATED
-------------------------------------------**

*Here is my latest Auth/RegisterController.php (I guess the latest version Laravel Framework version 5.3.24 breaks Auth up in various controllers)*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Company;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'company_name' => 'required|unique:companies,company_name',
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $company = \App\Company::create(['company_name'=>$data['company_name']]);

        $company->users()->create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return $company;

        // User::create([
        //     'name' => $data['name'],
        //     'email' => $data['email'],
        //     'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        // ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is fine, the 2nd is effectively the same but makes less logical sense. Both in fact should work, however. In either example, is a company created, and does that have an `id` in your companies table which is not `0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see now. You are doing it in wrong direction. You have to make company first. Then a user. Something like this:

```
   $company = \App\Companies::create(['company_name'=>$data['company_name']]);
   $company->users()->create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
```

If you think about it, it makes sense. If you create an user first, you can't populate company_id as company does not exist yet.

One thing I strongly recommend is to name your models in singular - Company not Companies as this is common convention.

Also, make sure you have defined users() method on Companies model

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class);
    }
```

This method is in plural as one company can have many users. It is not required but makes more sense.

Also, relationship on User model (your method Company()) should be:

```
public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Company::class);
    }
```

First, convention is to write method names starting with lowercase letter (camelCase). Second, your User model has hasMany relationship defined - which is wrong. User does not have many companies, but he belongs to company.

If for any reason you want to create user first, then the approach would be to create an user, create a company and then take id of the company and update user.

Something like this:

```
$user = \App\Users::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
$company = \App\Companies::create(['company_name'=>$data['company_name']]);
$user->company_id = $company->id;
$user->save();
```

-------------- UPDATE BASED ON QUESTION UPDATE ----------------

Make sure you return $user on create() method, not a $company, as it expects user to be returned.

```
$company = \App\Companies::create(['company_name'=>$data['company_name']]);
$user = $company->users()->create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);
return $user;
```

Comment: Weird, this didnt work on the install where I had adminlte, entrust and landlord packages installed.  But when I did a fresh install (no packages) this worked fine.  I did however encounter an error on the fresh install after registering.  Checking the database it looks like everything was inserted like it was suppose to.  Why am I receiving this error: http://imgur.com/a/JR8RW

Comment: It looks like you maybe imported something wrong. Can you please post your AuthController as it looks now?

Comment: Just updated in question, ran `php artisan --version` and found out I'm running Laravel Framework version 5.3.24 which breaks the Auth up in various controllers

Comment: You get this error because you return $company in your create() method. It expects user to be returned in order to authenticate it. Take a look at my last solution and return user at the end. It will work fine.

Comment: Or just do: 
$user = $company->users()->create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
return $user;

Answer (score 1):

Try making 'company_id' fillable in your User model. Create method has protection for mass assignment. You can't insert data that is not listed in $fillable array.